# Debian 11 hangs while booting after kernel update to 5.10.0-21

Tags: debian, kernel, boot, upgrade, hang

Debian 11 hangs while booting after kernel update to 5.10.0-21. Interestingly, when I'm selecting previous kernel (5.10.0-20) everything works ok. Tried several times. Any idea?

Cheers,
Leszek

Comment: That is called a regression. Some patch included in the later kernel doesn't work for your HW. You may find it and report it.

Comment: thanks, could you recommend some method of investigating which hardware causes the issue? simply looking at dsmeg ie `journalctl -o short-precise -k -b -1`? or is there better way?

Comment: It's not the HW, it's the new kernel. Regression testing is the only thing which will tell you for sure which new patch has broken it for you.